# Best options for exporting data from one MySQL db table to another db table

Tags: mysql

Kinda racking my brain here trying to do what I thought would be simple to do.  I'm trying to move to a shell script/MySQL option for getting data from one table in a db to a staging table in another db. Basically truncate table db2.stage_customer_log, then db1.customer_log -> db2.stage_customer_log.  I tried a couple options with limited success on each, and I'm ready for suggestions.

The first think I tried was:

```
mysqldump -p dbname -u uname customer_log > stage_customer_log.csv --no-create-info
```

But it turned out that wasn't a good option since the resulting file was an INSERT into the original table name.  So I'd have to do a little manipulation to get it to work.

Next, I created a shell script with this:

```
#!/bin/sh
mysql -h hostname -P 99999 -u uname -p --database dbname <<STOP

SELECT * FROM customer_log INTO OUTFILE 'stage_dm_customer_log.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'; 

\q
STOP
test $? = 0 && echo "Your batch job terminated gracefully"
```

This gave me the result I wanted (comma delimited file), but it put the file in the MySQL directory (even if I entered an absolute path, or './' or whatever). Seeing Im hosted on Amazon, the second part (the importing) doesn't work, because I get access errors.

Then I went back to the first option when I read more on the options.  My final command was this:

```
mysqldump -p dbname -u uname customer_log --no-create-info --no-create-db --tab='/tmp/' --fields-optionally-enclosed-by='"' --fields-terminated-by=',' --fields-escaped-by='' --lines-terminated-by='\n' --verbose
```

but again ended up with a file name that had to be manipulated.

I finally tried Pentaho to bring in tables, and I don't know if its our instance but it takes quite a long time for such little records (32 min for 85,000).  So, I dont need specifics but what is the best route to go for something like this? What have others implemented?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both of the databases reside on the same host, then you can run this command:

```
INSERT INTO db2.stage_customer_log (column1, column2, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM db1.stage_customer_log
WHERE [your filters here]
```

But, if they are on different servers, then this might be helpful:

```
mysqldump -u user1 -ppassword1 -h host1 [some options here] db1 stage_customer_log | mysql -u user2 -ppassword2 -h host2 [some options here] db2
```

`mysqldump` always saves the csv file on the server computer and sql dump on the client side.

**UPDATE 1**

Another trick, could be either using MySQL Workbench (you could save the dump files on your local hard drive) or using [FEDERATED storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/federated-storage-engine.html).

Comment: Actually I should point that out.  I wish they were, but unfortunately  they are not only on different machines, but one is Amazon EC2, and they other RDS, so I dont have shell access to do the import.  I can only use "mysqlimport" for the second options.

Comment: If you want to use script only, then how about making use of the `FEDERATED` storage engine?  You could also make use of MySQL Workbench.  More information in the update 1 to my answer.

Comment: That was it.  I went this route and got it to work just the way I wanted. 

mysqldump -u user1 -ppassword1 -h host1 [some options here] db1 stage_customer_log | mysql -u user2 -ppassword2 -h host2 [some options here] db2
Thank you

Comment: Glad to help you out.  Best of luck!